# Why same nsmutablearray gives me valid value and a null on different functions used

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have a NSMutableArray with some objects of type Notes i.e. my class with attributes, iD,note,noteTitle.. I am using the notes array to populate a tableview, and on click, I am trying to open another controller view, to show that specific table row clicked

My code are :

when controller load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     Notes * myNotes =[[Notes alloc] init];
     notes = [myNotes getMyNotes];
     [super viewDidLoad];    

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView        numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",((Notes *) [notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).noteTitle ];   

    // here i am using  my notes nsmutablearray from above method to populate tableview list of titles.. and it is populated fine.

    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.jpg"];
    return cell;
  }
```

Now when I click a row, I am trying to just see if, I will be getting title, body and it for that certain note..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

   long selectedRow = indexPath.row;    
  NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",((Notes *) [notes objectAtIndex:selectedRow]).notes];

   NSLog(@"%@",title);

  }
```

But I am getting null this time... 
why same code in above function is populating my table view but here not even logging it.

Thank you in advance....

Comment: `.notes` vs `.noteTitle`? Could the `notes` property be `nil` at this point, but not the `noteTitle` that you see in the `UITableView`?

Comment: sorry that was mistake... but now, even after i changed it, its giving me null, though that same code is giving me my all note titles 

NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",((Notes *) [notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).noteTitle ];

Comment: do the debugging properly

Answer (score 0):

You can try in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
Notes *note = [[Notes alloc]init];
note = [notes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",note.notes];
NSLog(@"%@",title);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: `Notes *note = [notes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];`. The alloc/init shouldn't be done.